# Can not get continuous input from client or server using java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am planning to create master and slave bots using Java Sockets.
I am testing on to something and have successfully implemented the following client and server programs:

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server{

    public static void main(String ... args){

        try{

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1201);
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String msgin = "", msgout = "";

            while(!msgin.equals("end")){
                msgin = din.readUTF();
                System.out.println(msgin);

                msgout = br.readLine();
                dout.writeUTF(msgout);

                // dout.flush();
            }

            s.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


class Client{

    public static void main(String ... args){

        try{

            Socket s = new Socket("10.0.0.49",1201);

            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String msgin = "", msgout = "";

            while(!msgin.equals("end")){

                msgout = br.readLine();
                dout.writeUTF(msgout);

                msgin = din.readUTF();
                System.out.println(msgin);


            }

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

}
```

The thing is that I want constant input from both server and the client.

Current Scenario:
Client sends and waits for server to respond.
Server sends and waits for the client to respond.

Desired Working:
Client can send as many messages, and not wait for the server and vice versa.

Comment: Hint: Use multi-threading, assign task to separate thread.

Comment: Create a separate thread for doing the `messaging` on both client and server side.